# Excel VBA to send different emails and log email details

Tags: vba, loops, email, logging

I'm new here and not very proficient, I tend to google what I need and piece it together so please don't feel like you'd be offending me by dumbing things down.

I'm trying to create a spreadsheet where I can send predetermined emails based on conditions in cells, and log the date those emails are sent in a table- hopefully something reasonably straightforward!

Currently working with [this table of information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GWbju.png) on Sheet2 and 3 text boxes on Sheet1 for each body of text and my very rudimentary vba attempt below- email set to display and commented send while testing.

I'm certain I've made a bigger meal of this than I need to, but the goal is to have a user input class, date and time in columns C:E. From there, Column K has an IF statement to determine whether to send email 1, 2 or 3 based on if F is empty (1st email), if F has a value (2nd email) or if G has a value (3rd email). As it stands, I can do this on 3 separate subs but cannot combine them, possibly because I'm trying to reference 'body' to different text boxes in the same sub? So below is the Sub for email 1. It's currently filtering K and copying data out of a table, into another range to then use as an email list (likely unnecessary) before clearing that pasted range and returning to the table.

I'm facing a problem in that if I click the button for this VBA and there are no '1's in column K, it selects all data in the table and sends an email to all. I'd like it to skip rows where C:E are empty and only email the 'outstanding' emails that have new input in those cells.

I'm also facing a problem in figuring out how to then move the class/date/time info over to column L:N (or 11:13 in the table) if K=1, to column O:Q if K=2, to column R:T if K=3, and to skip the row if K="". Also trying to populate the appropriate email column with the date of sending, so If K=1, F=today(), If K=2, G=today(), IF K=3, H=today(). I learned that copying and pasting filtered cells into filtered cells is not straightforward.

Any help would be hugely appreciated! Thank you.
PS- eventually would like to figure out how to remove dates in the log older than 30 days and move the data accordingly- ie, if email 1 is older than 30 days, email 2 details become email 1, so we can maintain a 3 strike in 30 days policy

```
Sub EMAIL1()

ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:= _
    "1"
Range("A3:E3").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.copy
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Range("A2").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Dim i As Integer
Dim name, email, body, subject, copy, class, classdate, classtime As String
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object

body = ActiveSheet.TextBoxes("TextBox 1").Text

i = 2
'Loop down name column starting at row 2 column 1
Do While Cells(i, 1).Value <> ""
    
    name = Split(Cells(i, 1).Value, " ")(0) 'extract first name
    email = Cells(i, 2).Value

    class = Cells(i, 3).Value
    classdate = Cells(i, 4).Value
    classtime = Cells(i, 5).Value
    
    body = Replace(body, "[Name]", name)
    body = Replace(body, "[Class]", class)
    body = Replace(body, "[Class Date]", classdate)
    body = Replace(body, "[Class Time]", classtime)

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
    With OutMail
         .To = email

         .subject = "Non attendance"
         .body = body
         .display
         '.Send
    End With
    
    body = ActiveSheet.TextBoxes("TextBox 1").Text
    
    i = i + 1
Loop

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing

Range("A2:E2").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.ClearContents
   Sheets("Sheet2").Select
   

ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=11
    MsgBox "Email(s) Sent!"
```

End Sub